# Fair Reentrant Lock C++

Tags: c++, concurrency

I'm working on a program which suffer from starvation when one thread is doing more work than another. Critical section is protected by a reentrant QMutex, which is not fair.

In Java, you can specify a fairness parameter for a lock. Does C++,(or boost libraries) have any fair reentrant lock available? Preferably up to C++11.

I did some research before, there is shared_lock in boost, but I do not need a read/write lock. Just a lock which will guarantee that each thread has equal chances to enter the critical section.

Thank you very much.

Comment: There's `std::mutex` with `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` since C++11, but they're not guaranteed to be fair. I believe the MSVC CRT implementation uses a wait queue, though, so they may be fair on that platform.

Comment: Yes.. but I need a fair lock...

Comment: Rather than use a fairness parameter, which is not generally available in C++, you may find that you obtain more control over the situation by priority queuing the work dispatch so that you can throttle 'heavy' operations to avoid starvation. It would clearly be more coding, but may give you a better result in the long run.

Comment: From OS viewpoint, all threads have similar chance to run, so if you have not set different priority to your threads and starvation happen on some threads, that means those thread have not assigned enough time by OS thread scheduler, however this will not happen. This reflect that your design may be problematic

Answer (score 2):

C++ thread primitives are really based on Posix threads, and Posix does not have any fair mutexes. However, your question indicates that there is a problem with your design. There are two issues here:

1. Re-entrant mutexes are sign of the problem. You need to be 100% in control of mutex ownership and lifecycle. If you need re-entrant mutex, it means, design is sloppy.
2. Thread starvation in your description is a result of improperly designed thread communication. If a thread needs a mutex held for the duration of the work, it means, you are effectively designing a single-threaded system, and need no threads whatsoever.

Comment: Well yeah, in principle, but often things aren't as simple as that ;-)

Comment: @Cameron, not in principle. In real life.

Comment: You may be right about reentrant, but you are not right about fairness and thread starvation. A thread can starve even in a simple scenario. Did a full course in concurrency where the problem was discussed extensively and now I met the problem in reality. Too bad that C++ have poor support for something which is really essential when developing multi-thread programs.

Comment: @Veaceslav, can you elaborate? I would like to see an example where thread starvation is not an result of bad design.

Comment: One thread is pooling a queue for new items. While pooling, it acquires a lock. Producer thread want to put something in the queue but is starved by the consumer thread which is constantly pooling and grabs a lock. This is one from my Java assignments which I solved with fair lock. Also, the real-case app: We have sqlite access which must be serialized. The program as a batch process which write a lot to database. And why batch process is active, the interface functionality which depends on getting data are starved.

Comment: @Veaceslav, you example is a clear demonstration of terrible design.